# Improve the performance of NumberOfDiscIntersections test in Codility

Tags: java, algorithm

**Question**

We draw `N` discs on a plane. The discs are numbered from `0` to `N − 1`. An array `A` of `N` non-negative integers, specifying the radiuses of the discs, is given. The `J`-th disc is drawn with its center at `(J, 0)` and radius `A[J]`.

We say that the `J`-th disc and `K`-th disc intersect if `J ≠ K` and the `J`-th and `K`-th discs have at least one common point (assuming that the discs contain their borders).

The figure below shows discs drawn for `N = 6` and `A` as follows:

```
A[0] = 1
A[1] = 5
A[2] = 2
A[3] = 1
A[4] = 4
A[5] = 0
```

There are eleven (unordered) pairs of discs that intersect, namely:

- discs 1 and 4 intersect, and both intersect with all the other discs;
- disc 2 also intersects with discs 0 and 3.

Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
```

that, given an array `A` describing `N` discs as explained above, returns the number of (unordered) pairs of intersecting discs. The function should return `−1` if the number of intersecting pairs exceeds `10,000,000`.

Given array `A` shown above, the function should return `11`, as explained above.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

- `N` is an integer within the range `[0..100,000]`;
- each element of array `A` is an integer within the range `[0..2,147,483,647]`.

**My Solution is as follows**

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
// import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
                Circle[] circleList = new Circle[A.length];
        //calculate left and right
        for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
            int radius = A[i];
            Circle circle = new Circle();
            circle.setX(i);
            circle.setLeft(i-radius);
            circle.setRight(i+radius);
            circleList[i] = circle;
        }
        
        int intersection = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
            //i+1 to avoid previously matched combination. i.e if i=2,j=1. this can //be excluded as it was already covered in i=1,j=2 
            for(int j=i+1; j<A.length; j++) {
                //System.out.println(i+" , "+j);
                Circle leftCir = circleList[i];
                Circle rightCircle = circleList[j];
                
                if(leftCir.right >= rightCircle.left) intersection++;
                
                if(intersection > 10000000) {
                    return -1;
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        return intersection;
    }

    static class Circle {
        int x;
        int left;
        int right;
        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }
        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
        public int getRight() {
            return right;
        }
        public void setRight(int right) {
            this.right = right;
        }
        public int getLeft() {
            return left;
        }
        public void setLeft(int left) {
            this.left = left;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Circle [x=" + x + ", left=" + left + ", right=" + right + "]";
        }
        
    }

}
```

But I am getting a TIMEOUT error. How can I improve the performance of this solution?
Is there a way by which I can eliminate the inner for loop?

And I found this question under the "Sorting" section. How can I use sorting in this?
I came across various solutions with out proper comments/definitions. Hence posting this question.

Comment: Did you check this answer? It seems an answer with an informative description.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510630/number-of-intersections-in-a-sequence-of-discs?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of intersections in a sequence of discs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510630/number-of-intersections-in-a-sequence-of-discs)

Comment: Both links point to the same answer which apparently solves the problem but imho the explanation is hard to understand, even though the one asking the question tried to clarify it.

Comment: you are right @maraca. Also, I struggling to figure out why it falls under the sorting section. If someone can explain, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to come up with a simpler solution that should run in O(nlogn) too. At least for me it is easier to understand, but maybe harder to implement. Some words about the problem and the solution:

- It is a bit mean because the maximum value for A is the maximum for integers in Java, so when you calculate the right boundary using integers it can overflow.
- The solution requires a data structure that can do the following operations in O(logn), e.g. a balanced tree (AVL tree, red-black tree) where each node also stores the number of nodes in its sub-tree, you can find such implementations online, I will just call it data structure in the code and explanation:

  - add element
  - remove min (optional)
  - get min (optional)
  - count number of elements <= x

  remove min and get min are optional because instead of removing elements you could use count twice, e.g. for elements in range [a, b], you do countSmallerEqual(b) - countSmallerEqual(a - 1). I explained and implemented with removing because I think it is easier to understand, but there is just a small adjustment required to use this method.

The solution explained:

1. Sort the circles by their left boundary and start processing the elements in order. Like this we only have to look at the right boundaries: an already processed circle only intersects the current circle if its right boundary is <= the right boundary of the current circle (unless the left boundary is the same, then they obviously intersect). So the data structure only needs to store the right boundaries.
2. Remove all elements that are smaller than the left boundary of the current circle from the data structure, they cannot intersect any more.
3. Collect the circles with the same left boundaries. Those do all pair-wise intersect. So we can use the sum formula to count the number of intersections for those circles: (n - 1) * n / 2.
4. Now we have to calculate the number of intersections with already processed circles. So for each circle in the collection count the number of elements which are <= the right boundary using the data structure.
5. Add all right boundaries of the collected circles to the data structure and continue with 2.

```
public int solution(int[] a) {
    long count = 0;
    DataStructure dataStructure = new DataStructure();
    // sort circles by left boundary
    Circle[] circles = new Circle[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        circles[i] = new Circle(i, a[i]);
    Arrays.sort(circles);
    // process sorted circles
    for (int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        // remove elements from data structure which are <= left of current
        while (!dataStructure.isEmpty() && dataStructure.getMin() < circles[i].getLeft())
            dataStructure.removeMin();
        // collect right boundaries of circles with same left boundary
        List<Integer> righs = new LinkedList<>();
        rights.add(circles[i].getRight());
        while (i + 1 < circles.length && circles[i + 1].getLeft() == circles[i].getLeft())
            rights.add(circles[++i].getRight());
        // add number of pair-wise intersections (they all intersect at left)
        count += (rights.size() - 1L) * rights.size() / 2L;
        // count the number of intersections with already processed circles
        for (Long r : rights)
            count += dataStructure.countSmallerEqual(r);
        // add elements to data structure
        for (Long r : rights)
            dataStructure.add(r);
    }
    return count <= 10000000L ? (int) count : -1;
}

@Getter
static class Circle implements Comparable<Circle> {
    private final long left;
    private final long right;
    public Circle(long index, long radius) {
        this.left = index - radius;
        this.right = index + radius;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Circle circle) {
        return Long.compare(this.left, circle.left);
    }
}
```